# Swift UITableViewCell showing data that's hidden by default

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a seemingly random issue, where some of the cells in my `UITableView` is showing data that's supposed to be hidden by default.

To explain the hidden data.

It's a stock portfolio, where you can tap on a cell to expand it (and see this data). When it closes the data is getting hidden again.

Here's a screenshot of the problem I'm facing causing random cells to display this data by default.

[image]

In the screenshot above it's the "RUS.TO" and the "CUB" cells that's displaying the hidden data.

Here's how the views and labels that's supposed to be hidden are set up:

```
// #Advanced data

    stockNameView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    stockNameView.hidden = true
    self.addSubview(stockNameView)

    purchasePriceView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    purchasePriceView.hidden = true
    self.addSubview(purchasePriceView)

    lastPriceView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    lastPriceView.hidden = true
    self.addSubview(lastPriceView)

    daysHeldView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    daysHeldView.hidden = true
    self.addSubview(daysHeldView)
```

The 8 labels that's overlapping are subviews of the above 4 views.

As you can see these 4 views are set to be hidden by default. So I don't think the issue lies in my cell class?

There's only one place in my code where I set the hidden value of these 4 UIViews to false.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("com.Stocks.portfolioCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! portfolioCell


    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.formulaWhiteColor()
    }

    if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
        cell.tickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.formulaBlueColor()
        cell.heightSeperator.hidden = false
        cell.stockNameView.hidden = false
        cell.purchasePriceView.hidden = false
        cell.lastPriceView.hidden = false
        cell.daysHeldView.hidden = false
        cell.endSeperator.hidden = false
        tableHeight.constant = tableHeight.constant+250
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.bounds.width, height: self.contentView.frame.height)
    }

    if lastCollapsing == true || currentCollapsing == true {
        cell.tickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.formulaDarkGrayColor()
        cell.heightSeperator.hidden = true
        cell.stockNameView.hidden = true
        cell.purchasePriceView.hidden = true
        cell.lastPriceView.hidden = true
        cell.daysHeldView.hidden = true
        cell.endSeperator.hidden = true
        lastCollapsing = false
        currentCollapsing = false
        tableHeight.constant = tableHeight.constant-250
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.bounds.width, height: self.contentView.frame.height)
    }

    if stocks.count > 0 {
        let formulaStock = stocks[indexPath.row]

        ticker = formulaStock.valueForKey("ticker") as! String!

        let fontAwesomeBlueAttribute = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.formulaBlueColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "FontAwesome", size: 12)!]
        let fontAwesomeGreenAttribute = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.formulaGreenColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "FontAwesome", size: 12)!]
        let latoBoldDarkGrayAttribute = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.formulaDarkGrayColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 12)!]
        if ticker != "CASH" {
            let tickerString = "  \(ticker)" as NSString
            var tickerAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: tickerString as String)
            tickerAttributedString.addAttributes(fontAwesomeBlueAttribute, range: tickerString.rangeOfString(""))
            tickerAttributedString.addAttributes(latoBoldDarkGrayAttribute, range: tickerString.rangeOfString("  \(ticker)"))
            cell.tickerLabel.attributedText = tickerAttributedString
        } else {
            let tickerString = "  \(ticker)" as NSString
            var tickerAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: tickerString as String)
            tickerAttributedString.addAttributes(fontAwesomeGreenAttribute, range: tickerString.rangeOfString(""))
            tickerAttributedString.addAttributes(latoBoldDarkGrayAttribute, range: tickerString.rangeOfString("  \(ticker)"))
            cell.tickerLabel.attributedText = tickerAttributedString
        }

        weight = formulaStock.valueForKey("weight") as! Float
        cell.weightLabel.text = "\(weight.roundTo(2))%"

        cell.filledWeightWidth.constant = CGFloat(weight/2)

        lastPrice = formulaStock.valueForKey("lastPrice") as! Float
        purchasePrice  = formulaStock.valueForKey("purchasePrice") as! Float
        percentDifference = ((lastPrice/purchasePrice)*100.00)-100


        if ticker == "CASH" {
            cell.changeLabel.text = ""
        } else if percentDifference > 0 {
            cell.changeLabel.text = ("+\(percentDifference.roundTo(2))%")
            cell.changeLabel.textColor = UIColor.formulaGreenColor()
        } else if percentDifference < 0 && percentDifference > -100 {
            cell.changeLabel.text = ("\(percentDifference.roundTo(2))%")
            cell.changeLabel.textColor = UIColor.formulaRedColor()
        } else if percentDifference == 0 {
            cell.changeLabel.text = ("\(percentDifference.roundTo(2))%")
            cell.changeLabel.textColor = UIColor.formulaGreenColor()
        } else {
            cell.changeLabel.text = "N/A"
            cell.changeLabel.textColor = UIColor.formulaDarkGrayColor()
        }

        cell.stockNameLabel.text = formulaStock.valueForKey("name") as! String!
        cell.purchasePriceLabel.text = "$\(purchasePrice)"
        cell.lastPriceLabel.text = "$\(lastPrice)"
        daysHeld = formulaStock.valueForKey("daysHeld") as! Int
        cell.daysHeldLabel.text = "\(daysHeld)"
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    return cell
}
```

But the section of code that sets the hidden values of a cell to be false. Requires my `selectedCellIndexPath` to be equal to the current indexPath that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is going through.

Here's where I set the `selectedCellIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("com.Stocks.portfolioCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! portfolioCell
    if let selectedCellIndexPath = selectedCellIndexPath {
        if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
            self.selectedCellIndexPath = nil
            currentCollapsing = true
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        } else {
            lastCollapsing = true
            self.selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([lastIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
            self.lastIndexPath = indexPath
        }
    } else {
        selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
        self.lastIndexPath = indexPath
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
    }
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Which should only ever be anything when I tap on a cell.

Every time I supply the UITableView with a new set of data I also make sure to run the following line of code:

```
(menuTabBarController.viewControllers as! [Portfolio_ViewController])[1].selectedCellIndexPath = nil
```

Which sets the `selectedCellIndexPath` to nil, to avoid any potential issues.

So, why are some random cells showing the information that's supposed to be hidden by default?

When I have been testing this bug, I have not tapped on any cells. So the selectedCellIndex should never even have a value at this point.

Comment: I had simillar problem, because I was adding the labels programicly as subViews, but never removing them. Instead of adding and hidding them, try to add them, when you want to show them, and remove them, when you want to hide them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reuse cells the old values still persists on it so everytime you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` you need to reset the default values or the last values still cached in it.

[From apple documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

> The table view’s data source implementation of
>   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always reset all content when
>   reusing a cell.

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely caused by cell reuse - if previously selected cell is used as non-selected one, `hidden` values of it's subviews won't change.

You can fix this by adding `else` branch:

```
if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
    ...
} else {
    // reset cell to non-selected state
    ...
}
```

Comment: UITableViewCells also have a `prepareForReuse` method that you can use to reset any state

Comment: Didn't try this solution, as the other answer was 2 lines less, but doing the same thing I reckon this would work too.

Comment: @chedabob I tried cell.prepareForReuse but that didn't fix my issue.

Comment: Sorry I should've made it clearer: You need to override that in your subclass and reset your view within that method

Answer (score 0):

After getting cell from `dequeueReusableCell`, do this. Clears load of junk data from view and it gives better performance too.

```
let cell = userTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "users", for: indexPath)


for v in cell.subviews {
    v.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @chedabob mentioned in his comment. UITableViewCell will call `prepareForReuse()` before it reuses the cell. Reset your views and value in it. So, inside your tableviewcell class override the method  `prepareForReuse()`

```
//Inside your UITableViewCell

override func prepareForReuse() {
       //Reset cell values here 
}
```